# Backup Couchbase 2.2 with cbbackup from 3.0

Tags: couchbase

Is it possible to take a backup of a Couchbase cluster v2.2 using [cbbackup](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbbackup_tool.html) from 3.0?

I am mainly aiming to use the feature of incremental updates which is un-available on 2.2. Hence using 3.0 cbbackup to get the backup of 2.0 cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to use the 3.0 version of `cbbackup` on older cluster, however incremental backup relies on new features on the actual Couchbase Server (specifically [DCP](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/dcp.html)) and so won't get access to incremental backup on a pre-3.0 cluster by using a 3.0+ version of `cbbackup`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I tried taking a backup of 2.2 using 3.0 cbbackup. The backup size was
2MB.
Next i tried an incremental backup and the data size was halved to 1MB. 

What can we conclude from this?